# What does this notation mean above the staff?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music, repeats

I'm learning piano and music theory. Today I came across this notation - a bracket line spanning across the width of the staff, and a number on the left. Could someone please tell me what it means? Thank you very much in advance!

[image: staff with mystical bracket line]